# How to pass props (that getting from Redux) from one Component to another (React/Redux)?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-router, react-router-dom

How to pass props (that getting from Redux) from WrapperComponent to InnerComponent (React/Redux)?

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { withRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import InnerComponent from "./InnerComponent ";

class WrapperComponent extends Component {
  state = {
    data: []
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <InnerComponent props={this.props} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  data: state.data
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(withRouter(WrapperComponent));
```

After rendered the WrapperComponent - the props are still not in. 
Any LifeCicle Methods can't help to resolve it.

Is It Possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible and it is recommended to do so, so you don't to need call all the HOC store each time via 'connect'. Call all concerned actions and reducers to your containers and pass them as props.

In this case, your reducer name is called data, you need to call it like this (I changed the props name to data, so you can call props.data to your child):

```
<InnerComponent data={this.props.data} />
```

Or you can pass all the props from the parents like this:

```
<InnerComponent {...this.props} />
```

Comment: Thank you!! So in that case `<InnerComponent props={this.props}` props - is the new props that I try to pass?

Comment: Yes in this case Props is the props that you called props, but you could give what ever name.
If you call props props, you will have to call in your child props.props. If you child is a class you'll have to call this.props.props, if functional component: props.props.